# Jetty: how to disable logging?

Tags: logging, jetty

I am trying to embed Jetty 6.1 in another program. Jetty is dumping INFO-log information and I need to turn it off. Is there a simple way to disable logging programmaticaly?

Comment: Did you find the solution? How about update your post!??

Answer (score 15):

A more concise version of Jeff Chern's answer:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(new NoLogging())
```

.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger;

public class NoLogging implements Logger {
    @Override public String getName() { return "no"; }
    @Override public void warn(String msg, Object... args) { }
    @Override public void warn(Throwable thrown) { }
    @Override public void warn(String msg, Throwable thrown) { }
    @Override public void info(String msg, Object... args) { }
    @Override public void info(Throwable thrown) { }
    @Override public void info(String msg, Throwable thrown) { }
    @Override public boolean isDebugEnabled() { return false; }
    @Override public void setDebugEnabled(boolean enabled) { }
    @Override public void debug(String msg, Object... args) { }
    @Override public void debug(Throwable thrown) { }
    @Override public void debug(String msg, Throwable thrown) { }
    @Override public Logger getLogger(String name) { return this; }
    @Override public void ignore(Throwable ignored) { }
}
```

Comment: Note: this is not appropriate for Jetty 6.1 (as the question indicated).  The `org.eclipse.jetty` package space didn't exist until Jetty 7.0

Comment: The answer below by @arcuri82 is the most appropriate configuration (no custom code) to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt This solution worked better for me than one by @arcuri82 - that approach still left one annoying message logged: `2018-12-26 17:20:31.752:INFO::main: Logging initialized @943ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog`

Comment: @EgorNepomnyaschih you can overcome that by setting `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.announce=false`.

Answer (score 15):

```
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class", "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog");
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "OFF");
```

This worked for me, but just make sure to call it before starting the server.

Comment: Despite originally being asked for Jetty 6, this was the cleanest solution I found, still relevant for Jetty 9.4.x.

Answer (score 5):

In Jetty Embedded you can try: org.mortbay.log.Log.setLog(null); Before call Server.

Comment: hint: **before** call server is important

Answer (score 3):

I've had success in creating a dummy logger that discards everything it's ever asked to log, and then passing it into `Log.setLog(...)`.

E.g.

```
private static class DummyLogger implements Logger {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "DummyLogger";
    }

    @Override
    public void warn(String msg, Object... args) {}

    @Override
    public void warn(Throwable thrown) {}

    @Override
    public void warn(String msg, Throwable thrown) {}

    @Override
    public void info(String msg, Object... args) {}

    @Override
    public void info(Throwable thrown) {}

    @Override
    public void info(String msg, Throwable thrown) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isDebugEnabled() {return false; }

    @Override
    public void setDebugEnabled(boolean enabled) {}

    @Override
    public void debug(String msg, Object... args) {}

    @Override
    public void debug(Throwable thrown) {}

    @Override
    public void debug(String msg, Throwable thrown) {}

    @Override
    public Logger getLogger(String name) {return this; }

    @Override
    public void ignore(Throwable ignored) {}

}
```

For reference, I used these packages:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger;
```

instead of the mortbay ones, but they should probably behave the same (or at least similarly).

Answer (score 3):

Set the `StdErrLog` level to `WARN`, before starting your server:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "WARN");
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog.setProperties(p);
```

Comment: This seems to work, though there is no `NONE` option. `expecting only [ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN]`

Comment: @ThomasAhle it's true, but I agree with their choice. It is not really a good idea to prevent any error to show up in the log.

Comment: @ThomasAhle There seems to be an `OFF` option though : `${name|hierarchy}.LEVEL=(ALL|DEBUG|INFO|WARN|OFF)`, source : http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.6.v20151106/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/StdErrLog.html

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(new jettyNoLog());
Logger.getLogger(jettyNoLog.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.OFF);
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getProperties().setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "OFF");
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getProperties().setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.announce", "false");
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getRootLogger().setDebugEnabled(false);
```

Comment: The `announce` setting is especially nice.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [debugging page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging) mentioned by Vinay:

> *Jetty uses the SLF4J logging infrastructure to bridge to commons-logging for JSP2.0. This means that commons-log messages are sent to the SLF4J interface.*
>
> *We ship the Simple log implementation, which will only output INFO level and above messages to stderr.*
>
> *However, you can replace the Simple log with any other SLF4J log implementation by removing the lib/jsp-2.0/slf4j-simple-1.0-rc5.jar and copying in the SLF4J impl of your choice. The core Jetty code has a soft dependency on SLF4J, meaning that if an SLF4J impl is found on the classpath at startup Jetty will direct all logging messages to it.*
>
> *Alternatively, you can remove the SLF4J jars altogether and use commons-logging instead by copying in the commons-logging jar and a commons-logging compliant log impl, such as log4j, to the lib/ directory. However, if you do that, be aware that as the core Jetty code does not use commons-logging, it will log messages to stderr instead. Read on to learn how to get the stderr log mechanism to print DEBUG level messages.*

So it's a matter of putting the right jar file. For instance, you could put a log4j compatible interface and configuring your log4j configuration file properly to mute completely jetty's logging statements or to be more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the server, call:

```java
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog logger = new org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog();
logger.setLevel(org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog.LEVEL_OFF);
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(logger);
```

This is basically the same as [in the answer by arcuri82](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43528092/3637482), but without the remaining single log line, which logger is used.

Answer (score 0):

Add configuration

```
log4j.category.org.eclipse.jetty=error
```

in the file **src/main/resources/log4j.properties**