# how can i turn off jetty debuging?

Tags: java, web-services, web, intellij-idea, jetty

I have a java app that runs jetty:

```
public class ServerRunner {

    private final static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LoggingUtils.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PromptoConfig.s.initLog();


        final int port = 8082;

        final Server jettyServer = new Server(port);
        final HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();

        // Creating the first web application context
        final WebAppContext webappContext = new WebAppContext();

        System.out.println("===== PromptoConfig.s.RESOURCES_BASE " + PromptoConfig.s.RESOURCES_BASE);
        webappContext.setResourceBase(PromptoConfig.s.RESOURCES_BASE);
        webappContext.setContextPath("/");

        System.out.println("===== PromptoConfig.s.WEB_XML_PATH " + PromptoConfig.s.WEB_XML_PATH);
        webappContext.setDefaultsDescriptor(PromptoConfig.s.WEB_XML_PATH);
//        webappContext.setTempDirectory(new File(temp));


        DBSQLConfig.s().DB = com.waze.prompto.config.DBSQLConfig.s.DB;


        webappContext.setExtractWAR(false);
        handlers.addHandler(webappContext);

        // Adding the handlers to the server.
        jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("failed to init jetty server", ex);
        } finally {
            jettyServer.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

i see in the logs debug info in intellij console:

```
633016 [org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@22fcf7abTimer] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session  - Scavenging sessions at 1496325042425
```

How can i turn this debug logs off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jetty: how to disable logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120370/jetty-how-to-disable-logging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have configured log4j on your environment.

```java
private final static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LoggingUtils.getLogger();
```

The output format is also not the default format from Jetty's internal `StdErrLog`

Yours

```
633016 [org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@22fcf7abTimer] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session  - Scavenging sessions at 1496325042425
```

Jetty's StdErrLog

```
2017-06-01 14:30:17.978:DBUG:oejs.session:main: SessionManager default maxInactiveInterval=1800
```

At this point, this is no longer a jetty logging configuration, but a log4j configuration.

Just set the `org.eclipse.jetty` logger level to INFO or WARN in your `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`

Comment: `Just set the org.eclipse.jetty logger level to INFO or WARN in your log4j.properties or log4j.xml` can you please explain how?

Comment: That is specific to your environment, with log4j it can be done in many possible ways.  Consult your log4j configuration files (wherever they may be).  See other questions on stackoverflow for hints ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763740/log4j-log-output-of-a-specific-class-to-a-specific-appender

Answer (score 0):

If you use **jetty-server** from eclipse

Add configuration

```
log4j.category.org.eclipse.jetty=error
```

in the file src/main/resources/log4j.properties