# How do I turn off org.eclipse.jetty logs in Google App Engine Java8?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, java-8, jetty-9

I'm deploying a Java8 standard environment and I cannot change the logging level, or turn off logs for `org.eclipse.jetty.*`.

I have tried:

- Creating a [jetty-logging.properties](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/default-logging-with-stderrlog.html) file in src/main/resources and configuring it via that file
- Setting a [JETTY_ARGS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime) variable in my app-engine.xml file:

  ```
  <env-var name="JETTY_ARGS"
    value="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
  ```
- Just using the java.util.logging `logging.properties` file in google app engine and setting: `org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL= WARN`

I'm not too sure how to get rid of logs like the following in my GAE logging:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP sendContent: Generated content (0 bytes) - DONE/HttpGenerator@23c0fcd1{s=END} (HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:83)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you set up your own Jetty logger that does 'nothing'? As mentioned [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059551/3058302)

Comment: I think I could if I used the app engine flex environment, but would prefer to just control everything in my logging.properties file. Also don't plan on leaving the standard environment if I can help it.

Comment: I could be wrong though. I'd have to see how much access I have to the jetty implementation underneath, but again, would prefer not to have to mess with it at that level