# How to disable slf4j in jetty

Tags: java, jetty, slf4j

I am using a self code logger and i dont want implement to slf4j.

And Jetty will prints:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

How to disable this stupid output?

Im not using Spring or something like that. I just import jetty library and it prints...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372056/how-to-turn-off-logging-from-slf4j

Comment: well im not using a Tomcat or Spring. I just import the jetty library and it prints

Comment: Then what about using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059551/5515060)?

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748518/13963086). (Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.9/slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar and put it in your classpath.)

Comment: Thanks NOPLogger worked!

Comment: For the record, Jetty isn't printing this, slf4j-api is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a slf4j-nop logger

Add this in dependencies block of build.gradle

kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:2.0.0-alpha1")
```